# WebGL shader LUT wrong results on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, three.js, glsl, webgl

I currently have a fragment shader in WebGL (powered by Three.js) that uses a texture as a Lookup Table (LUT). This was originally developed on/for my laptop but I later decided to extend it to work on mobile. I opened the page up on my iPhone to notice it looked completely different. After stripping my code back to just see what I was getting from the LUT I noticed the results were different. My LUT code is below

```
    uniform sampler2D texture1;
    uniform sampler2D lutMap;
    varying vec2 vUv;
    precision highp float;

    vec3 rgb2hsv(vec4 c)
    {
        vec4 K = vec4(0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 / 3.0, -1.0);
        vec4 p = mix(vec4(c.bg, K.wz), vec4(c.gb, K.xy), step(c.b, c.g));
        vec4 q = mix(vec4(p.xyw, c.r), vec4(c.r, p.yzx), step(p.x, c.r));

        float d = q.x - min(q.w, q.y);
        float e = 1.0e-10;
        return vec3(abs(q.z + (q.w - q.y) / (6.0 * d + e)), d / (q.x + e), q.x);
    }

    void main() {
        vec4 inColour = texture2D(texture1, vUv);

        // convert to hsv
        vec3 hsv = rgb2hsv(inColour);
        // scale it up 
        hsv = vec3(floor(hsv[0] * 128.0), floor(hsv[1] * 128.0), floor(hsv[2] * 128.0));
        // map to how we've stored our value
        float posF = ((hsv[0] * 128.0*128.0) + (hsv[1] * 128.0) + hsv[2]);
        // calculate the actual position in our map
        vec2 posV = vec2(floor(posF / 2048.0) / 2048.0, 1.0 - mod(posF, 2048.0) / 2048.0);

        // the colour
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(lutMap, posV);
    }
```

The `precision highp float` line was added in attempt to test if it was precision causing this problem but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I have checked on http://webglreport.com/ on both my working laptop and not working phone and they give the same values for fragment shader precision. Is there anything else obvious I should try? Just for clarity, as this was initially causing problems on my laptop, I tell my textures to use nearest filter mapping, e.g.

```
tex.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
tex.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
tex.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
tex.generateMipmaps = false;
tex.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: The question as-is is very interesting, but setting up a small online *running* example would definitely lower the barrier to actively take a more in-depth look at the issue.

Comment: If you put up a sample put as a snippet here on SO, not some external site that will make the question useless when the external site disappears.